# Смысл в async/await | Почему async не делает метод асинхронным

Tags: c#, async-await, асинхронность

Чем отличается асинхронность этого кода, который написан по Microsoft

```
        static async Task<int> MakeBurger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Начало бургера --------");
        int c = 0;
        while (c < 7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Бургер -> {c}");
            await Task.Delay(100); //Ожидаем выполнения задачи
            c++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Конец бургера --------");
        return c;
    }
```

от асинхронности кода, который представлен далее

```
        static void Advertising()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Реклама {i}");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    static Task AdvertisingAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(Advertising); //Сам является задачей
    }
```

Это вопрос о том, что сбивает с толку в самом начале обучения: почему ключевое слово Async не делает метод асинхронным? Зачем мне нужно реализовывать Await в методе, который и без него возвращает Task. Зачем компилятор разбивает код метода на части? Моё предположение: возможно из-за того, что это влияет на доступ к ресурсам. Но как? Или это из-за паттерна TAP, который говорит, что код должен быть написан в синхронном стиле.

Проделав поиски нашла такую фразу, но она мне всё-равно не объяснила, почему нельзя сразу использовать задачу без этих прерываний:

> Если вы недавно занимаетесь асинхронным программированием, рекомендуем обратить внимание на различия между синхронным и асинхронным поведением. Синхронный метод возвращает управление, когда его работа завершается (шаг 5), тогда как асинхронный метод возвращает значение задачи, когда его работа приостанавливается (шаги 3 и 6). Когда асинхронный метод в конечном счете завершает работу, задача помечается как завершенная и результат, при его наличии, сохраняется в задаче.

[с сайта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

Зачем возвращать задачу, на которой произошло прерывание, если весь метод можно сделать задачей?

UPD: Возможно это связано с тем, что async/await строит машину состояний и с помощью await делает прерывания в потоке? Грубо говоря во вселенной async есть только один поток, а задачи распараллеливаются с помощью прерываний? Почему тогда машину состояний со множеством прерываний использовать лучше, чем один поток?

Comment: _Грубо говоря во вселенной async есть только один поток_ - грубо говоря, да.

Comment: А это эффективно? Насколько я понимаю, каждый await берёт из пула потоков один для себя. На сайте Microsoft написали статью о том, что для легковесных операций лучше as/aw, а для тяжеловесных - task. Для меня это значит, что в коде не должно быть много await, но как там с циклами? Постоянно переключаться между контекстами - это дорого.

Comment: Мне кажется тут не хватает понимания разницы между задачами cpu-bound и io-bound. Для первых - многопоточность, для вторых - асинхронность. Потоки имеет смысл делать, когда они что-то реально будут перемалывать, делать какие-то вычисления. А если планируется ждать ввода-вывода, то достаточно и одного потока, который вернётся к тому месту, где он прервался на ожидание, когда на ввод-вывод поступит новая информация.

Comment: @CrazyElf, именно это я и хотела узнать. Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда по сути, async-await лучше использовать только Task.Delay ?